# Get files/folders from solution in VS Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, directory, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to list all folders, subfolders & files in a foreach. The trick is that I want to do it from a visual studio extension. Side note, I'm using VS for mac.

I'm using these documentation pages :

[Extension tree reference](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/extension-tree-reference/) & [API overview](https://www.monodevelop.com/developers/articles/api-overview/)

Right now, I'm kinda lost but came up with this :

```
string curdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var root = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(curdir);
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(".", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} in {1}", file, curdir);
}
```

Since this is an extension, there is also code to run this from a menu. I think that code is irrelevant to the question.
When I run the program (extension), it starts another IDE in which my custom menu button is available, which will run this code.

When I run it, I see some files *from the extension project*, and not the project I opened in the new IDE that just started.

Trying to be absolutely clear here :
Visual Studio (we'll call VS1) is building and compiling my extension into another instance of Visual Studio (we'll call VS2). My extension is then used into that new instance (VS2), but when the code runs, it shows files & folders from VS1 instead of VS2.

I do not want that because the goal is to be able to use this extension to list files of any project, and not list the files of the extension. Ultimately performing some cleaning in said files.

I think my issue is one of those :

- I can't identify the solution I'm executing this code from. Correct API but wrong use.
- Not using the correct API to list all files & folders.

To give some clarification, the next step here is, in the end, to right clic on a project and list all files & folder for that project. Which will in turn be a stepping stone to some file cleanup.

My question is :

How can I correctly list files & folders of a solution, from extension code ? The code I'm running here seems to be pointing towards the project that is *running* and not the one it's being executed from.

This leads me to believe I'm not using the correct API ; but the docs are quite unclear and difficult to navigate, I'm not sure at all what I should be using.

Comment: Code is always executed within a specific context. If you execute the plugin in VS2 the files listed would be VS2 ones. Looks normal behavior to me. Edit: I could be wrong, consider adding a [mcve] to get better, more specific feedback

Comment: That makes sense and is reassuring. Edit : Did not want to clutter the question but I'll make some more tests and include that in the question.